# What is the equivalent of C's double pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a C/C++ newbie, so sorry if my question seems straightforward.

It has always been claimed that pointers in C++ are useless. See for example the answer from Konrad Rudolph here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56935/why-are-pointers-not-recommended-when-coding-with-c

Below I have an example for which I am wondering how can I replace the C code by a C++ code without using any pointers:

```
  double *A;                              
  double **a;

  A=new(std::nothrow) double[4];

  a=new(std::nothrow) double*[2];

for (unsigned int q=0, k=0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        a[k]=A + q;
        q+=2;
    }

  delete[] A;
 delete[] a;
```

The programmer codes up as above because he/she needs the pointer `a` to point to the pointer `A` so that when modifying the variable to which `A` points, he/she does not to modify `a`.

Sometimes, the programmer does a `for loop` with a[k] from k={0,1,2,3}, and sometimes he does a double `for loop` a[i][j] from i,j={0,1}.

How can I replace this by a C++ code without using pointers?

Comment: The answer referenced does not say "pointers in C++ are useless", but it recommends the use of smart pointers.

Comment: "It has always been claimed that pointers in C++ are useless." It has never been claimed - C++ is deeply dependent on the use of pointers, as at heart are all  programming languages.

Comment: No he did not say that. He said : "For somebody who knows modern C++, it’s clear that you very rarely need any pointers (either smart or raw; except when using them as iterators)"

Comment: You missed the part about iterators. Pointers are fine iterators. They are also fine nullable things. The problem is too many people seem to associate the word "pointer" with dynamic allocation and ownership.

Comment: And from Konrad's answer "There are definitely legitimate uses of (raw) pointers. "

Comment: You can write C++ code that does all of the same things with pointers that C code can do.  You can also do many new things in C++, and some of those new things let you write safer, cleaner, non-raw-pointer solutions to problems that you could only have solved in C by using pointers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth : The end of his phrase is quite important too: "But I (and many professional C++ programmers) maintain that these cases are exceedingly rare. "

Comment: @RangerBob "rare" is not the same thing as "useless".

Comment: What do you expect with `a[k]=A + q`?

Comment: This question has a false premise. Furthermore many problems are solvable without pointers. But asking how to replace pointers makes no sense. The `C++` equivalent of pointers is pointers. They are simply not needed as much in `C++` as in `C`.

Comment: i grew up in the believe that if you dont have enough `new` and `delete` in your code then you arent really writing c++. Its nice that times have changed and some beginners get pushed away from overusing pointers right from the start, but I hope there will be a time when pointers are not such a religious topic anymore and we dont need articles titled "don't use f*cking pointers" anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some important clarity: what you're being advised is to not use *Raw, Owning Pointers*. It's perfectly fine to use Non-Owning Raw Pointers iff you know, as a fact, that you're not responsible for `delete`ing said memory; or Owning Smart Pointers iff you are responsible for said memory, but `delete`ing will be handled by the RAII principles of the smart pointer class.

So let's consider what's happening in your code:

- `A` represents ownership over a runtime-sized array of `double`s.
- `a` represents ownership over a runtime-sized array of non-owning pointers to `double`s, all of which will come from `A`.

Simply creating an array of objects is either best represented by `std::array`, for compile-time-sized arrays, or `std::vector`, for runtime-sized arrays. So we'll need the latter. This is easy to construct:

```
std::vector<double> A(4);//Array of 4 doubles.
```

Since `a` will contain non-owning pointers to `A`, which we know will outlive `a`, it's perfectly fine to use raw pointers inside this vector:

```
std::vector<double*> a(2);
```

Then, we assign into it, just like your code was already doing:

```
//Use size_t for sizes in C++. Always, always, always.
for (size_t q = 0, k = 0; k < 2; k++){
    a[k] = A + q;//Uh oh, this doesn't compile!
    q += 2;
}
```

Ah, hmm. `A` isn't a raw pointer anymore. Well, we'll need to use a member function of `std::vector` to get the raw pointer.

```
//Use size_t for sizes in C++. Always, always, always.
for (size_t q = 0, k = 0; k < 2; k++){
    a[k] = A.data() + q;//There we go.
    q += 2;
}
```

Finally, because our memory is RAII-managed, we don't need to `delete` this memory afterwards:

```
//No longer needed
//delete[] A;
//delete[] a;
```

So the final code will end up looking like this:

```
std::vector<double> A(4);
std::vector<double*> a(2);
for (size_t q = 0, k = 0; k < 2; k++){
    a[k] = A.data() + q;
    q += 2;
}
```

This code is nearly identical to the C-style code you wrote originally, and is much easier to read and maintain. The only difference is the small amount of overhead in `std::vector`, which the compiler can optimize away for the final program.

If you want code which *literally* emulates the behavior of your original code, this would be the result. I don't recommend it, because it's more complicated than you need, and limits how the code can be used, but if you just want the direct port (or just want to see how Smart Pointers fit into this kind of problem), here it is:

```
std::unique_ptr<double[]> A = std::make_unique<double[]>(4);
std::unique_ptr<double*[]> a = std::make_unique<double*[](2);
for (size_t q = 0, k = 0; k < 2; k++){
    a[k] = A.get() + q;
    q += 2;
}
```

Comment: And even `std::vector<double*> a{&A[0], &A[2]};` (with `{}` and not `()`).

Comment: Can you give me more information about the difference between  Non-Owning Raw Pointers and Raw, Owning Pointers?

Comment: @RangerBob What you need to know about is "Ownership" in C++, which is a pretty broad topic, where Dynamic Memory/Pointers/Smart Pointers are just a subset of that topic. [The C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-library#unique-ptr) is a good resource to start with, And [Bjarne Stroustrup's (short) paper](http://www.stroustrup.com/resource-model.pdf) on a similar topic is also good to look into, as he tends to write in relatively plain language to keep things accessible to laypeople. Also do some google searches for "C++ Ownership semantics" and look around.

Comment: It's not a property of the pointers, but of your logical program structure. Whatever entity is responsible for tracking the lifetime of a resource and then deleting/freeing/otherwise releasing it, is the _owner_. If your code has a raw pointer variable eventually used to delete an allocated object, that is the owning pointer. Actual ownership is really split between the pointer and the code using it, which is why smart pointers are generally preferred for clearly locating ownership in one place

Comment: Thanks for those informations!

Comment: @Xirema : In your example, would be nice to replace `std::vector<double*>` by a iterator vector ?

Comment: @RangerBob Iterators are generally a good/better solution for this kind of problem, only issue is that the type system makes it a bit verbose. `std::vector<std::vector<double>::iterator>` is the full type of this kind of vector, or `std::vector<std::vector<double>::const_iterator>` for iterators that can't alter the other vector's contents. Can replace with `std::vector<decltype(A.begin())>` or `std::vector<decltype(a.cbegin())>` to slightly reduce the verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

One of the primary uses of pointer-to-pointer in C is to return a pointer value:

```
error_t Allocate Object(Object ** ptr);
```

While the same will work in C++ it can be made somewhat more intuitive by making the function take a reference-to-pointer instead of pointer-to-pointer:

```
error_t AllocateObject(Object *& ref);
```

This way the calling code can simply pass the pointer variable (instead of needing to use & to take its address) and the function definition can simply assign to the parameter (rather than needing to dereference it with *).

Answer (score 0):

The modern C++ equivalent of your example code would use smart pointers for ownership, and iterators to access array elements:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    // Define our types:
    using A_array = std::array<double, 4>;
    using A_iterator = A_array::iterator;

    // Make smart pointers to manage ownership for us:
    auto const A = std::make_unique<A_array>();
    auto const a = std::make_unique<std::array<A_iterator, 2>>();

    // Normally, we'd just put these in automatic storage, as
    // they are small, and don't outlive the function scope:
    // A_array A;
    // std::array<A_iterator, 2> a;)

    {
        // Populate a with iterators to A's elements
        auto target = A->begin();
        for (auto& element: *a) {
            element = target;
            target += 2;
        }
    }

    // No need for delete[] at end of function or at any other
    // return statement.
}
```

Comment: Could I mix your solution with the one by @Xirema? I mean can I use a vector of iterator instead of std::vector<double*> a(2);? This would avoid me using smart pointers, isn't?

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you're asking.  I used a vector because we have a compile-time constant size, so it's a better choice than a vector here.  But if your size might vary, then a vector would be suitable.  Note that if `A` is a vector, then you need to know when its references could be invalidated, just as you would with pointers (in fact, vector iterators are usually implemented as pointers).

Comment: Thanks! What i also meant is can we simply remove the smart pointers in your example? Can we have your example without any raw/smarts pointers?

Comment: Yes, you can (and I've shown in comments a non-pointer version - you obviously need to change `->` to `.` and `*a` to `a`).  Take the code and experiment with it to see what you like and what doesn't work (and if you're not sure whether something that seems to work is good C++, come back to SO with a question; it will likely be a good question, with your new understanding!)